# PHP namespace and frameworks

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to user composer to add some frameworks to my code but I am getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Time\DOMPDF'
```

The App\Time is my namespace:

```
<?php namespace App\Time;
```

the code I am trying to use is this:

```
require_once "/home/timeext/public_html/dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array('Attachment'=>'0'));
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a namespace for a file any unqualified object is assumed to be in that namespace. To use something *outside* of the declared namespace you need to either use its fully-qualified name:

```
namespace your\app;
$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
```

Or import the object into the local namespace.

```
namespace your\app;
use \DOMPDF;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();`
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php